# DOMPDF - Defining DOMPDF_DPI on a case per case basis?

Tags: php, pdf, dpi, dompdf

Is there something like:

```
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->resolution(200);
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
```

Instead of having to set in the dompdf_config.inc.php, as I have multiple PDF files and they need different DPI.

Comment: Covering all your bases, I see ;)

Comment: Shotgun approach works sometimes :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using the latest code from github then you can do the following:

php

```
$dompdf = new DOMPDF;
$dompdf->set_option( 'dpi' , '200' );
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
```

The full option list can be seen [in the source](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/blob/5ba5e695e5b8e85367760cb4432c35d16bfa7e9a/include/dompdf.cls.php#L200).

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about set_option - this fixes my issue.

Answer (score 8):

As of 2017 the [Dompdf documentation](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/Usage) says to set options (search for setHttpContext for an example) including DPI as follows:

```
$options = new Dompdf\Options();
$options->setDpi(150);
$dompdf = new Dompdf\Dompdf($options);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setOptions`:

```
$pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
$pdf->setOptions(['dpi' => '600']);
```